# AGOL WebApp for offline use

Tags: arcgis-online, offline

I'm building an app with the Web AppBuilder of ArcGIS Online. 
I heard it would be possible to download the app so that it could be used offline or deployed on another server. In my case, i would just need to be able to use it offline. 
I managed to download the app which gave me a zip folder but once it's done i have no idea what to do with all these files to be able to visualize the app. I have very basic notions of HTML/CSS only. I opened the index.html file but i receive this error message: "Unable to load config.json?wab_dv=2.15 status: 0"
Does anyone have any leads to share?

[image]

Comment: your Website must use IIS/Tomcat > https://community.esri.com/thread/219107-unable-to-load-configjsonwabdv29-status-404-and-an-error-in-handleas-transformation-of-response (MIME type needs to know what to do with the json file *your config.json looks tied to notepad)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Mapperz. I went through the threat you sent so i checked my IIS manager but .json is already in the MIME types. (Just like the person in the thread). I still don't really know how to untie this .json from notepad.

Comment: this is for powerpoint but the same method https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-dis-associate-a-default-file-extension-in/bfc5e996-28be-4bd9-98f8-465022d79b5f

Comment: I checked but it doesn't look like notepad is tied by default to .json files. Is there anything else that may be missing on my computer so that the .json can't be loaded properly?

Comment: When you say you "opened the index.html file", did you just click (or doubleclick) the index.html file to open the application? 
Are you accessing the application using a URL that starts with http? You need to do the latter.

Comment: Indeed, i just clicked on the .html file. Do I need to use a url that starts with http even if i just want to open the application offline?